# How to reply to the sender of a channel and manage state

Tags: go, channel, goroutine

I would like to know how to reply directly to the sender of a channel in Go. More interesting is how to identify the sender for later use.

I am comparing this to Elixir GenServer where I can reply to the sender directly or broadcast to everyone. Is this feature missing in Go?

Everywhere I read about channels in Go I cannot find how to do this.

Also, GenServers in Elixir hold states becomes it is a infinite running process. Does Go have semething similar to hold and pass state? If not how is this accomplished?

Comment: https://golang.org/doc/effective_go#chan_of_chan

Comment: There is no rule for `GenServer` to be running infinitely, moreover many have a limited lifetime.

Comment: On a channel you can pass another channel (as mentioned), a callback function, other sync primitives like a Mutex or Cond, or any other value that can be used to affect the state of the program.

Comment: Officially, goroutines aren't supposed to have any identity, and there's no "safe" way to identify them. Therefore, there's not an inherent idea of a "sender" as being a tangible thing you can work with in the program.

Comment: An "infinite running process" in Go is just a goroutine that doesn't return.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Communicating with a channel sender

As already mentioned, a [channel of channels](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go#chan_of_chan) is a way to respond directly to the channel sender. Here is an example:

```
package main

func main() {
    // Make a communication channel by creating a channel of channels
    c := make(chan chan struct{})
    // Start a sender with the communication channel
    go sender(c)
    // Receive a message from the sender, in this case the message is a channel itself
    r := <- c
    // Send response to the sender on the channel given to us by the sender
    r <- struct{}{}
}

func sender(c chan chan struct{}) {
    // Create a channel the receiver will use to respond to us
    r := make(chan struct{})
    // Send the channel to the receiver
    c <- r
    // This is the response received after the received got the message
    <- r
}
```

As to your second question about identifying a specific sender, you may be able to use something like [goroutinemap](https://pkg.go.dev/k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/util/goroutinemap) which allows you to manage the lifecycle of named go-routines. This pattern isn't common however, and if you need to identify a specific channel sender, it's possible you could (and should) re-design your solution.

### Managing application state

This depends entirely on your application and what it does. Edit: according to OP, the application is a chess game over websockets. You could consider creating a data structure with references to both player's websocket connections, as well as the game state between the players. This data structure would get created when a game is started, then the data structure could manage the messages back and forth between the players and the updating of the game state internally. Perhaps something like

```
type GameState struct {
    Player1 *websocket.Conn
    Player2 *websocket.Conn
    // Add any game state needed here
}

func (s *GameState) run(ctx context.Context) {
    // Send messages between websocket connections here and update game state accordingly
}
```

Comment: I think I kind of understand this. But I am thinking more of a state of the sender. The example is a chess game between 2 people using websockets. To keep state between this two players without affecting a state between any other 2 players etc. So a global state wont work because 1 game cannot affect others game.

Comment: I updated my post with an example of how you could manage game state between two players over websockets. Without really diving into your application, this is the best I can do.

Comment: Wow that is so simple. Does this mean I just need to add for example go run(...) because I will fire a go routine for every 2 players that log into the app to play?

Comment: Yes, `run` should be called in a go-routine. Then the main go-routine is free to continue pairing players and setting up `GameState`s